# XT IDE causes BASIC not to load properly on IBM 5155

Tags: ms-dos, ibm, xt-ide

I recently picked up an XT IDE. It works fine for the most part, but when I tried to load BASIC samples from the original IBM DOS 1.1 floppy(I was booting from it), the system hung up, only showing a blinking cursor. When I have removed the card, everything was working. How can I fix it?

Comment: If the EPROM is socketed in the XT-IDE board: Does it work if you remove the EPROM from the board?

Comment: @MartinRosenau I haven't tried that, but the card has a ROM Enable switch. When I disabled the ROM, basic worked fine, but I couldn't boot from IDE.

Comment: What Version is the card and what ROM address is jumpered?

Comment: @Raffzahn I don't know the version. The card I bought is https://rover.ebay.com/rover/0/0/0?mpre=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ebay.com%2Fulk%2Fitm%2F332861819840 Everything is set to default.

Comment: The default XT-IDE settings load the XT-IDE ROM at 0xD000, which shouldn’t cause issues with BASIC. However that doesn’t mean it should be plain sailing... You’re more likely to get an accurate answer on [the XT-IDE BIOS thread on VCF](http://www.vcfed.org/forum/showthread.php?17986-XTIDE-Universal-BIOS).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out I can just use GW BASIC instead of BASIC and BASICA.
GW BASIC loads up just fine.

Comment: For reference: BASIC is stored in ROM,. BASICA.COM is a program that loads BASIC with a number of extensions/enhancements/additional features, but it still relies on the ROM BASIC for shared functionality. GWBASIC.EXE is a self-contained program that does not depend on the ROM BASIC at all.